# Using Dask from script

Tags: python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed

Is it possible to run `dask` from a python script?

In interactive session I can just write

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()
```

as described in all tutorials. If I write these lines however in a `script.py` file and execute it `python script.py`, it immediately crashes.

I found another option I found, is to use MPI:

```py
# script.py
from dask_mpi import initialize
initialize()

from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()  # Connect this local process to remote workers
```

And then run the script with `mpirun -n 4 python script.py`. This doesn't crash, however if you print the client

```py
print(client)
# <Client: scheduler='tcp://137.250.37.84:35145' processes=0 cores=0>
```

you see that no cores are used, accordingly scripts run forever without doing anything.

How do I set my scripts up correctly?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to create processes from within a Python script you need to protect that code in an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block

```
from dask.distributed import Client

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = Client()
```

If you want to use dask-mpi then you need to run it with `mpirun` or `mpiexec` with a suitable number of processes.

Comment: Could you also provide the correct example for usage of `dask_mpi`? Then I will mark the answer as accepted. Even if the ifmain guard, `mpirun -n 4 python script.py` still uses neither cores nor processes.

Comment: Hrm, my first guess would be that your MPI system isn't set up well, but presumably you've used it before.  I don't know.  I would ask the experts at github.com/dask/dask-mpi

Comment: I am obviously no expert, but if I run C++ code with `mpirun -n CORES` the correctly run in parallel. So unless `dask` relays on something special, I would say everything is OK. Thanks for the help, I will ask.